# Change Location of zcompdump Files

Tags: zsh

Is it possible to change the location of .zcompdump and .zhistory files generated by ZSH? 
They are polluting my Home Directory. 
One possible solution I found was changing the value of `$ZDOTDIR` to `$HOME/.config/zsh`. I did the following, but it does not seem to work (temp files are still created in the home directory).

```
$ cat ~/.zshenv
ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.zsh
. $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
```

Comment: I found that setting `export ZDOTDIR=/your/path/here` in the global configs works (for me, that's located at `/etc/zsh/zshenv`).

Comment: @User12345 that works, but if you use ZSH as default shell you gotta put `.zshrc` at `$ZDOTDIR`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`.zcompdump` files are produced to speed up the running of `compinit`, Which initializes the shell completion in `zsh`. You could [specify an explicit dump file](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Use-of-compinit) by `compinit -d <dumpfile>` in your `.zshrc` to change the location where compdump are stored.

Change the value for [`HISTFILE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-HISTFILE) to set different location to store you zsh command history.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by changing $ZDOTDIR. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ man zshall
/Use of compinit

 To speed up the running of compinit, it can be made to produce a dumped 
configuration that will be read in on future invocations; this is the 
default, but can be turned off by calling compinit with the option -D.  The 
dumped file is .zcompdump in the same directory as the startup files (i.e. 
$ZDOTDIR or $HOME); alternatively, an explicit file name can be given by 
`compinit -d dumpfile'.  The next invocation of compinit will read the 
dumped file instead of performing a full initialization.
```